# pure javascript table row pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination

I try to do pagination table but I want to reference table row to show 3 data per page

How Could i do

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/578hmpv2/

This Code

```
var current_page = 1;
var records_per_page = 3;
var l = document.getElementById("listingTable").rows.length


function prevPage()
{
    if (current_page > 1) {
        current_page--;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function nextPage()
{
    if (current_page < numPages()) {
        current_page++;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}
    
function changePage(page)
{
    var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
    var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
    var listing_table = document.getElementById("listingTable");
    var page_span = document.getElementById("page");
 
    // Validate page
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();


    for (var i = (page-1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page) && i < l; i++) {
   
             listing_table.rows[i].style.display = ""              
    }
    
    page_span.innerHTML = page + "/" + numPages();

    if (page == 1) {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (page == numPages()) {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

function numPages()
{
    return Math.ceil(l / records_per_page);
}

window.onload = function() {
    changePage(1);
};
```

How can I change it to make it perfect? Sorry for my bad English, can't explain all what I need, hope you understand what I need!

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want. I've tried to keep the code more or less structured how you wrote it, but I've changed a few things:

I've used `onclick` rather than a javascript scheme href because the stack overflow code editor didn't run the href.

I've used `current_page` rather than a hard-coded `1` in the `onload` function.

Other than that I think the comments explain the situation.

Note that I've had to add one to the loop and subtracted one when doing the page count to allow for the header row.

```js
var current_page = 1;
var records_per_page = 3;
var l = document.getElementById("listingTable").rows.length

function prevPage()
{

    if (current_page > 1) {
        current_page--;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function nextPage()
{
    if (current_page < numPages()) {
        current_page++;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}
    
function changePage(page)
{
    var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
    var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
    var listing_table = document.getElementById("listingTable");
    var page_span = document.getElementById("page");
 
    // Validate page
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

    [...listing_table.getElementsByTagName('tr')].forEach((tr)=>{
        tr.style.display='none'; // reset all to not display
    });
    listing_table.rows[0].style.display = ""; // display the title row

    for (var i = (page-1) * records_per_page + 1; i < (page * records_per_page) + 1; i++) {
        if (listing_table.rows[i]) {
            listing_table.rows[i].style.display = ""
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    
    page_span.innerHTML = page + "/" + numPages();

    if (page == 1) {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (page == numPages()) {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

function numPages()
{
    return Math.ceil((l - 1) / records_per_page);
}

window.onload = function() {
    changePage(current_page);
};
```

```html
<table id="listingTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
    <td>Page 3</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a onclick="prevPage()" href='#' id="btn_prev">Prev</a>
<a onclick="nextPage()" href='#' id="btn_next">Next</a>
page: <span id="page"></span>
```

Comment: That work Thanks!! but can u explain This Code `[...listing_table.getElementsByTagName('tr')].forEach((tr)=>{
        tr.style.display='none'; // reset all to not display});`   on Traditional Function ? What is [...

Comment: `forEach` operates on arrays (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). `getElementsByTagName` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a collection, which is iterable. The spread operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) effectively converts the collection into an array so you can use forEach on it. It's pretty opaque, and you can rewrite it with a for loop quite easily if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    listing_table.rows[i].style.display = "none"
  }
```

add this in your changePage function

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9b2Lqm5/4/)