# How to limit the number of visible pages shown in pagination with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The pagination limit is not defined. I want to show the pagination in this format of 1/4, and the next and previous buttons will work accordingly. Also, on the first and last pages, clicks should be disabled. You can see it at the bottom of the table. Please help me in order to accomplish this. I tried but couldn't do it. That's why I am looking for expert help.

```js
        const paginationNumbers = document.getElementById("pagination-numbers");
        const paginatedList = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
        const listItems = paginatedList.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
        const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
        const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");

     const pageSize = 2;
        const paginationLimit = 2;
        const pageCount = Math.ceil(listItems.length / paginationLimit);
        let currentPage = 1;

        const disableButton = (button) => {
            button.classList.add("disabled");
            button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
        };

        const enableButton = (button) => {
            button.classList.remove("disabled");
            button.removeAttribute("disabled");
        };

        const handlePageButtonsStatus = () => {
            if (currentPage === 1) {
                disableButton(prevButton);
            } else {
                enableButton(prevButton);
            }

            if (pageCount === currentPage) {
                disableButton(nextButton);
            } else {
                enableButton(nextButton);
            }
        };

        const handleActivePageNumber = () => {
            document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-number").forEach((button) => {
                button.classList.remove("active");
                const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute("page-index"));
                if (pageIndex == currentPage) {
                    button.classList.add("active");
                }
            });
        };

        const appendPageNumber = (index) => {
            const pageNumber = document.createElement("button");
            pageNumber.className = "pagination-number";
            pageNumber.innerHTML = index;
            pageNumber.setAttribute("page-index", index);
            pageNumber.setAttribute("aria-label", "Page " + index);

            paginationNumbers.appendChild(pageNumber);
        };

        const getPaginationNumbers = () => {
            for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
                appendPageNumber(i);
            }
        };

        const setCurrentPage = (pageNum) => {
            currentPage = pageNum;

            handleActivePageNumber();
            handlePageButtonsStatus();

            const prevRange = (pageNum - 1) * paginationLimit;
            const currRange = pageNum * paginationLimit;

            listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
                item.classList.add("hidden");
                if (index >= prevRange && index < currRange) {
                    item.classList.remove("hidden");
                }
            });
        };

        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            getPaginationNumbers();
            setCurrentPage(1);

            prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
            });

            nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
            });

            document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-number").forEach((button) => {
                const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute("page-index"));

                if (pageIndex) {
                    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        setCurrentPage(pageIndex);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
       .result {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    
    

 /* Responsive Table Start */
    
    .rstable {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 16px 0px;
    }
    
    .rstable table {
        font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .rstable tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    .rstable tr td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 9px;
        color: #333;
    }
    
    .rstable th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px 9px;
        background: #004287;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .rstable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f9fbfdc4;
    }
    
    .rstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #dae9f3;
    }
    
    .rstable tr td a {
        color: #004287;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
        .rstable table {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .rstable table {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        .rstable thead {
            display: none;
        }
        .rstable td:first-child {
            text-align: left;
            display: inline-grid;
            width: 90%;
        }
        .rstable td {
            text-align: left;
            display: inline-grid;
            width: 26%;
            vertical-align: top;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        .rstable td:before {
            content: attr(data-title);
            font-weight: 500;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #000;
        }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
        .rstable td {
            width: 23%;
        }
    }
    /* Responsive Table Ends */ 

   .arrow-right,
        .arrow-left {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 8px;
            height: 8px;
            border-top: 2px solid #000;
            border-left: 2px solid #000;
        }
        
        .arrow-right {
            transform: rotate(135deg);
        }
        
        .arrow-left {
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .pagination-container {
            width: calc(100% - 0rem);
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0;
            padding: 0rem 0;
            justify-content: right;
            /* text-align: center; */
        }
        
.pagination-number, .pagination-button {
    font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
        
        .pagination-number:hover,
        .pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
            background: #fff;
        }
        
        .pagination-number.active {
            color: #fff;
            background: #0085b6;
        }
```

```html
                    <!-- Result Start -->
                    

                    
                    <!-- Result Table Starts -->
                    
                        <div class="rstable">
                          <table id="paginated-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Joined</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Airi Satou</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Accountant</td>
            <td data-title="Office">No1</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">1</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar1</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">01</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Germany</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome1</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">97</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td data-title="Position">CEO</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">2</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar2</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">02</td>
            <td data-title="Country">India</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome2</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">96</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Ashton Cox</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Technical Author</td>
            <td data-title="Office">Software Engineer</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">3</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar3</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">03</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Japan</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome3</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">95</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Bradley Greer</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Integration Specialist</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">4</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar4</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">04</td>
            <td data-title="Country">UK</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome4</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">94</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Software Engineer</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">5</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">05</td>
            <td data-title="Country">USA</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome5</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">93</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">6</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">06</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Canada</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome6</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">92</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Bruno Nash</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Sales Assistant</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">7</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">07</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Italy</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome7</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">91 </td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Caesar Vance</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Javascript Developer</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">8</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">08</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Mexico</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome8</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">90</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

                    </div>
                    
                    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;align-items: center;">

                        <div class="pagination-container">
                            <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-button" aria-label="Previous page" title="Previous page">
                            <span class="arrow-left"></span>
                    </button>
                            <div id="pagination-numbers">
                            </div>
                            <button class="pagination-button" id="next-button" aria-label="Next page" title="Next page">
                            <span class="arrow-right"></span>
                        </button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Result Table Ends -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add your total pageCount with your actual page number in your function appendPageNumber() use pageNumber.innerHTML = `${index}\\${pageCount}` (with template string, pls note a backslash is an escape character so you need to escape the backslash with 2 backlashes) and to disable button use the attribute disabled whith condition wanted (you can check it in devtools disabled attiribute added. Your handlePageButtonsStatus is also handling the disabling status. You should also set these condtions in your setCurrentPage, like this when you click on page numbers and if you are at first or last page arrow buttons are disabled

```js
const paginationNumbers = document.getElementById("pagination-numbers");
const paginatedList = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
const listItems = paginatedList.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");

const pageSize = 2;
const paginationLimit = 2;
const pageCount = Math.ceil(listItems.length / paginationLimit);
let currentPage = 1;


const disableButton = (button) => {
    button.classList.add("disabled");
    button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
};

const enableButton = (button) => {
    button.classList.remove("disabled");
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
};

const handlePageButtonsStatus = () => {
    if (currentPage === 1) {
        disableButton(prevButton);
    } else {
        enableButton(prevButton);
    }

    if (pageCount === currentPage) {
        disableButton(nextButton);
    } else {
        enableButton(nextButton);
    }
};

const handleActivePageNumber = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-number").forEach((button) => {
        button.classList.remove("active");
        const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute("page-index"));
        if (pageIndex == currentPage) {
            button.classList.add("active");
        }
    });
};

const appendPageNumber = (index) => {
    const pageNumber = document.createElement("button");
    pageNumber.className = "pagination-number";
    pageNumber.innerHTML = `${index}\\${pageCount}`; //for adding total page number
    pageNumber.setAttribute("page-index", index);
    pageNumber.setAttribute("aria-label", "Page " + index);
    paginationNumbers.innerHTML=''
    paginationNumbers.appendChild(pageNumber);
};
    

const getPaginationNumbers = (theCurrentPage) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
        theCurrentPage = theCurrentPage ?? 1
        if(i==theCurrentPage){appendPageNumber(i)}
    }
};

const setCurrentPage = (pageNum) => {
    currentPage = pageNum;
    if(currentPage===1){prevButton.disabled = true} // disable button when currentPage equal first page by pressing page number
    if(currentPage===pageCount){nextButton.disabled = true}// disable button when cureentPage equal last page by pressing page number
    handleActivePageNumber();
    handlePageButtonsStatus();

    const prevRange = (pageNum - 1) * paginationLimit;
    const currRange = pageNum * paginationLimit;

    listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.classList.add("hidden");
        if (index >= prevRange && index < currRange) {
            item.classList.remove("hidden");
        }
    });
};

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    getPaginationNumbers();
    setCurrentPage(1);

    prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
        if(currentPage===1){prevButton.disabled = true}// disable button when cureentPage equal first page 
        getPaginationNumbers(currentPage);
    });

    nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
        if(currentPage===pageCount){nextButton.disabled = true}// disable button when cureentPage equal last page 
        getPaginationNumbers(currentPage);
    });

    document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-number").forEach((button) => {
        const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute("page-index"));

        if (pageIndex) {
            button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                setCurrentPage(pageIndex);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.result {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}




/* Responsive Table Start */

.rstable {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 16px 0px;
}

.rstable table {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.rstable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.rstable tr td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 9px;
  color: #333;
}

.rstable th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  background: #004287;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.rstable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f9fbfdc4;
}

.rstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #dae9f3;
}

.rstable tr td a {
  color: #004287;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .rstable table {
      font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .rstable table {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 400;
  }
  .rstable thead {
      display: none;
  }
  .rstable td:first-child {
      text-align: left;
      display: inline-grid;
      width: 90%;
  }
  .rstable td {
      text-align: left;
      display: inline-grid;
      width: 26%;
      vertical-align: top;
      color: #333;
      font-weight: 400;
  }
  .rstable td:before {
      content: attr(data-title);
      font-weight: 500;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #000;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
  .rstable td {
      width: 23%;
  }
}
/* Responsive Table Ends */ 

.arrow-right,
  .arrow-left {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      border-top: 2px solid #000;
      border-left: 2px solid #000;
  }
  
  .arrow-right {
      transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  
  .arrow-left {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .hidden {
      display: none;
  }
  
  .pagination-container {
      width: calc(100% - 0rem);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 0rem 0;
      justify-content: right;
      /* text-align: center; */
  }
  
.pagination-number, .pagination-button {
font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
cursor: pointer;
height: 2rem;
width: 2rem;
border-radius: 0.2rem;
}
  
  .pagination-number:hover,
  .pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
      background: #fff;
  }
  
  .pagination-number.active {
      color: #fff;
      background: #0085b6;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Result Start -->
                    

                    
                    <!-- Result Table Starts -->
                    
                    <div class="rstable">
                      <table id="paginated-list">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>Train</th>
                                  <th>Type</th>
                                  <th>Zone</th>
                                  <th>From</th>
                                  <th>Dep</th>
                                  <th>To</th>
                                  <th>Arr</th>
                                  <th>Dur</th>
                                  <th>Halts</th>
                                  <th>Runs On</th>
                                  <th>Dist</th>
                                  <th>Speed</th>
                                  <th>Classes</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15011 Kashi Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">97 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15012 Pushpak Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">96 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15013 Godan Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">95 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15014 Golden Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">94 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15015 Lucknow Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">93 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15016 SLN Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">92 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15017 Sitapur Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">91 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td data-title="Train">15018 Darbhanga Express</td>
                                  <td data-title="Type">SuperFast</td>
                                  <td data-title="Zone">CR</td>
                                  <td data-title="From">LTT</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dep">15:30</td>
                                  <td data-title="To">GKP</td>
                                  <td data-title="Arr">06:15 +1 night</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dur">7h 55m</td>
                                  <td data-title="Halts">11</td>
                                  <td data-title="Runs On">S - T - T F -</td>
                                  <td data-title="Dist">632 km</td>
                                  <td data-title="Speed">90 km/hr</td>
                                  <td data-title="Classes">SL | 3A | 2A</td>
                              </tr>

                          </tbody>
                      </table>

                  </div>
                  
                  <div style="width: 100%; display: flex;align-items: center;">

                      <div class="pagination-container">
                          <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-button" aria-label="Previous page" title="Previous page">
                          <span class="arrow-left"></span>
                  </button>
                          <div id="pagination-numbers">
                          </div>
                          <button class="pagination-button" id="next-button" aria-label="Next page" title="Next page">
                          <span class="arrow-right"></span>
                      </button>

                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: I was asking for somewhat like this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452939/pure-javascript-table-row-pagination". Page number should change on clicking next or previous.

Comment: I was asking for somewhat like this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452939/pure-javascript-table-row-pagination". Page number should change on clicking next or previous. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok I see, makes sens actualy no need to have all the page if you add the totalpage number below

Comment: I am editing my answer with a correct shot for that in a second, I hope. Pls check

Comment: I also used the nullish operator theCurrentPage = theCurrentPage ?? 1 to give it the default value of 1 before getting a value with eventlistener. Now should work nicely

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I want one more help regarding the table search option. Do I post another question to which you can reply, or should I update this question only?

Comment: Yes pls post another question and I will sure have a look at it if I Can answer Thanks and happy my code helped you. Enjoy coding

Comment: Also pls dont forget to upvote and accept answer if it helped you. Thks

Comment: I have posted a new question. Please take a look and help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Shoeb, I will for sure today later on thks for the upvote 

Comment: Please reply to my new question.

Comment: Hello Shoeb I will have a look and Reply hopefuly just a little busy